# knockout.js applying checkbox predefined initial-state or default state with some boolean variable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I would like to learn how to control whether the checkbox  state (checked or unchecked) is initially applied with the predefined states or default states (unchecked) depending on the state of some boolean variable

I have the template code here : http://jsfiddle.net/8sg501yj/

```
function DemoItem(id, name, state) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.Name = ko.observable(name);
  self.Selected = ko.observable(state);
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.availableItems = ko.observableArray([]);


  self.init = function() {
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(1, 'One', true));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(2, 'Two', true));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(3, 'Three', false));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(4, 'Four', true));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(5, 'Five', true));
  };

  self.relayState = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.availableItems, function(item) {
        return item.Selected();
      });

    },
    write: function(value) {
      if (value) {
        console.log("associate item ");
      } else {
        console.log("disasociate item ");
      }
    }
  })
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.init();
```

and the HTML is :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"> </script>
Available Items:
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.availableItems">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Selected" />
  <span data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + Name()"></span>
  <br/>
</div>
```

This code applies the predefined states already. but I would like to adapt it or change it so that I have some boolean varaible, and by setting or unsetting that variable, initial states apre either applied, or checkboxes are unchecked (default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-reading your question a few more times I'm thinking perhaps you're specifically asking about a boolean switch to toggle whether the initial values get set or not. If that's the case you could simply pass a boolean to your `init` function that controls whether the initial values are applied.

```js
function DemoItem(id, name, state) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.Name = ko.observable(name);
  self.Selected = ko.observable(state);
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.availableItems = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.init = function(applyStates) {
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(1, 'One', applyStates && true));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(2, 'Two', applyStates && true));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(3, 'Three', applyStates && false));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(4, 'Four', applyStates && true));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(5, 'Five', applyStates && true));
  };
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.init(false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"> </script>
Available Items:
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.availableItems">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Selected" />
  <span data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + Name()"></span>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something very similar was already answered yesterday so you might need to clarify your question more if it wasn't answered satisfactorily, but I'll give a go at answering what I think you're asking.

Knockout binds your javascript view-model to the DOM so that changes in your data are automatically reflected in the UI. The only thing you need to do is bind to an observable, which you have. Any changes to your `DemoItem.Selected` will cause the checkboxes to check/uncheck accordingly. If Selected starts as true then the checkbox will start as checked.

> but I would like to adapt it or change it so that I have some boolean
>   varaible, and by setting or unsetting that variable, initial states
>   apre either applied, or checkboxes are unchecked (default)

You already have a boolean variable. `DemoItem.Selected` is a boolean. If you modify its value at any time the checkbox will check/uncheck accordingly, because knockout has bound the UI to that boolean value with what is referred to as two-way binding. That means the UI automatically updates the data, and the data automatically updates the UI as well.

In the snippet below there's a timer set to change the value of one checkbox after 1 second.

```js
function DemoItem(id, name, state) {
  var self = this;

  self.id = ko.observable(id);
  self.Name = ko.observable(name);
  self.Selected = ko.observable(state);
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.availableItems = ko.observableArray([]);


  self.init = function() {
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(1, 'One', true));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(2, 'Two', true));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(3, 'Three', false));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(4, 'Four', true));
    self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(5, 'Five', true));
  };
  
  //Example changing a boolean value after 1 second
  setTimeout(function(){
    self.availableItems()[0].Selected(false); //uncheck
  }, 1000)
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"> </script>
Available Items:
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.availableItems">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: Selected" />
  <span data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + Name()"></span>
  <br/>
</div>
```